# Find __INITIAL_STATE__ API url in website

Tags: python, reactjs, web-scraping

I want to scrape a website that contains a JSON inside after the "window.**INITIAL_STATE**=". Although I am able to scrape it by parsing the HTML, I want to know how I can find (if exists at all) the API where that data comes from. I have also checked some APIs that documented in their developers site, but they miss some information that is only available in that **INITIAL_STATE**

My goal is to do the request directly to an API instead of having to load the entire HTML to then parse it.

[Here](https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-theshadse1/) is the website Im trying to get info from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script is being loaded in the initial html, it's not pulled from any API. You can get that script data like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
       'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}


url = 'https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-theshadse1/'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data_script = soup.find('script', string=re.compile("INITIAL_STATE"))
data = json.loads(data_script.text.split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')[1])
print(data['state'])
```

Result in terminal:

```
{'brazeApiKey': 'f714b0fc-6de5-4460-908e-2d9930f31339', 'menuVersion': 'VCE.1b_tZDFq8FmpZNn.ric9K4otZqBy', 'restaurantId': '17395', 'countryCode': 'uk', 'language': 'en-GB', 'localDateTime': '2022-08-04T00:41:58.9747334', 'canonicalBase': 'www.just-eat.co.uk', 'androidAppBaseUrl': [...]
```

You can analyze and dissect that json object further, to get what you need from it.